# When is CompletableFuture actually completed?

Tags: java, completable-future

Here's the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CompletableFuture<String> r1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return "41";
    });
    CompletableFuture<String> r2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "42");
    CompletableFuture<String> r3 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("I'm called.");
        return "43";
    });
    CompletableFuture.allOf(r1, r2, r3).thenRun(() -> { System.out.println("End."); });
    Stream.of(r1, r2, r3).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Somewhat curiously, without actually completing the `CompletableFuture` from `allOf(...)`, e.g. calling its `join()`, I get the following output:

```
I'm called.
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@<...>[Not completed, 1 dependents]
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@<...>[Completed normally]
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@<...>[Completed normally]
```

May I know what's causing the JVM to treat/think that `r1` has [1 (estimated number of) dependent `CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#getNumberOfDependents--), while it decides to straightforwardly complete `r2` and `r3`? The only difference I can see is just the `try-catch`, so is the answer as simple as that?

For comparison, I get the expected waiting time of 5 seconds and the following output when I actually do a `join()` at the end. If it helps, I'm encountering this on Java 8 Update 40 JVM.

Modification:

```
// ...
CompletableFuture.allOf(r1, r2, r3).thenRun(() -> { System.out.println("End."); }).join();
Stream.of(r1, r2, r3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
I'm called.
// <note: 5-second wait is here>
End.
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@<...>[Completed normally]
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@<...>[Completed normally]
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@<...>[Completed normally]
```

Comment: "it decides to straightforwardly complete r2 and r3" - no way; it's just that they are completed so fast, before `forEach(::println)` is called.

Comment: @bayou The println doesnt care if they are completed or are you referring to something else?

Comment: I mean, when `println(r2)` is executed, `r2` happens to be completed by the executor. that is not guaranteed of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`r1` and `r2` are `CompletableFuture`s for two independently submitted async tasks.

> May I know what's causing the JVM to treat/think that r1 has 1
>   (estimated number of) dependent CompletableFuture, while it decides to
>   straightforwardly complete r2 and r3

It doesn't. By the time you call the `println` on these instances, `r2` and `r3` have completed normally (they don't do much). `r1` hasn't (the thread that would have completed it is most likely sleeping).

The call to `allOf` is not blocking. It will return a `CompletableFuture` of its own that will be completed when all the `CompletableFuture` you gave them are done. You chain that into another `CompletableFuture` with `thenRun` which, since `r2` and `r3` are done, simply depends on `r1`, ie. it is completed when `r1` completes.

You choose to discard the reference to this `CompletableFuture` but the task submitted to `thenRun` is scheduled. If you add a

```
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

at the end of your original program, you'll see your `End.` log printed when `r1` completes and, consequently, the one returned by `thenRun`.

---

Note that, unless otherwise specified, your async tasks within the `CompletableFuture` (eg. submitted through `supplyAsync`) are all ran within the default `ForkJoinPool` which uses daemon threads. Your application will exit before the the 5s has elapsed unless you choose to block somewhere and wait for that time to pass.

Comment: *"Your application will exit before the the 5s has elapsed unless you choose to block somewhere and wait for that time to pass"*. Thanks for mentioning the obvious, I failed to pick this up myself. :D

Comment: For completeness, note that you can wait specifically for the completion of the tasks submitted to the common pool by calling `ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(...)`.